# DataTable - Select only find row where value is less than 10?

Tags: c#, .net, select, datatable, row

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out what's going on with the Select method of DataTable. Here's the data that I got back in a DataTable, called `VotePeriods`:

`PeriodID` `Description`

`11` `Test 11`

`10` `Test 10`

`9` `Test 9`

...

...

`1` `Test1`

Here's the code to select the period based on PeriodID:

```
if (VotePeriods.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataRow[] vp = VotePeriods.Select("PeriodID = " + voteperiod);

    if (vp.Length > 0)
    {
        return vp[0];
    }
}
```

For some reason, if `voteperiod` is 9 or less, then I have the correct row selected. But if I pass in a `10` or `11`, I have no data back, even though in my DataTable, PeriodID `10` and `11` exists. Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I've tested your code and it works both for PeriodID = 10 and 11. I also don't see anything wrong with it - it should work, and if not - problem must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: The problem is with the `PeriodID` being String instead of int! Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope below will work. Keep in mind to add single quotation for values always when using the select method with DataTable.

```
if (VotePeriods.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataRow[] vp = VotePeriods.Select("PeriodID = '" + voteperiod +"'");

    if (vp.Length > 0)
    {
        return vp[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using LINQ to select?  I've had bad luck with a DataTable.Select before.

```
if(VotePeriods.Rows.Count > 0)
{

      var vp = from x in VotePeriods.AsEnumerable()
               where x["PeriodID"] == voteperiod
               select x;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data type of your PeriodID column is numeric, like `int`:

```
VotePeriods.Columns.Add("PeriodID", typeof(int));
```

Comment: @downvoter:  hmmm, according to the OP's comment my answer was the correct one yet you DVed it.